# how to do a getElementById on an ASP.NET control

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have an element on my page.

```
<asp:Button ID="buttonToFind" runat="server" OnClick="SomeProcess" />
```

In javascript I'm trying to find this control using:

```
document.getElementById("buttonToFind");
```

However it can't seem to find the control. My understanding is that the asp:Button gets changed to an input element? This input has a new ID that contains the original ID but with a lot of extra characters therefore I can't find the original ID on the page?

Is this correct?

Also given this how would I go about specifying the correct ID to search for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any server control will be gave new client side Id so yuo can use the ClientId of any control you wana pass to Javascript :)
so

```
document.getElementById('<%= buttonToFind.ClientID %>');
```

should be your answer

Comment: How is it that an answer which is a duplicate of the other 3 answers, and posted 3 hours after the rest get's marked as correct? I'm at a loss.

Comment: If the OP checks his question 3 hours later, he just sees it as the first response if SO sorts by "newest".  I think it should default to sorting by "oldest".

Answer (score 3):

You need the [ClientID](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientid.aspx) property of the control. In ASP.NET 4 you can also set the [ClientIDMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientidmode.aspx) to Static. [Source](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/03/30/cleaner-html-markup-with-asp-net-4-web-forms-client-ids-vs-2010-and-net-4-0-series.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Your understanding is correct.

This will work if the JS is on the ASPX/ASCX markup:

```
document.getElementById('<%= buttonToFind.ClientID %>');
```

If the JS is external, you'll need to do extra work (e.g use a literal to hold the ID's, or register a script).

Comment: Make sure your .NET language is VB.NET or you'll get an error. (C# is case sensitive.)

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the server control's client id:

```
document.getElementById("<%=buttonToFind.ClientID%>");
```